# Specifying Math Environment in Lua Function

Tags: function, lua

The following works.

```
function userdata(x)
      local _ENV = math
      return (x)
  end
  print(userdata(math.sin(2)))
```

However the following doesn't work.

```
function userdata(x)
      local _ENV = math
      return (x)
  end
  print(userdata(sin(2)))
```

How to avoid typing .math everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setmetatable(_G, {__index = math})

function userdata(x)
    return (x)
end

print(userdata(sin(2)))
print(max(3, pi))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to link the environment only with userdata function? This may affect other functions.

Comment: But you are invoking `sin` outside of the function's body.  The environment of the function will affect calculations only inside of it.

Comment: That is the purpose of function. To invoke math environment when it is called.